# Add additional layers to the Huggingface transformers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I want to add additional `Dense` layer after pretrained `TFDistilBertModel`, `TFXLNetModel` and `TFRobertaModel` Huggingface models. I have already seen how I can do this with the `TFBertModel`, e.g. [in this notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/dhruv1234/huggingface-tfbertmodel):

```
output = bert_model([input_ids,attention_masks])
output = output[1]
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32,activation='relu')(output)
```

So, here I need to use the second item(i.e. item with index `1`) of the `BERT` output tuple. According to the [docs](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#tfbertmodel) `TFBertModel` has `pooler_output` at this tuple index. But the other three models don't have `pooler_output`.

So, how can I add additional layers to the other three model outputs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like `pooler_output` is a `Roberta` and `Bert` specific output.

But instead of using `pooler_output` we can use a few `hidden_states`(so, not only last hidden state) with all models, we want to use them because [papers report](http://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-bert/) that `hidden_states` can give more accuracy than just one `last_hidden_state`.

```py
# Import the needed model(Bert, Roberta or DistilBert) with output_hidden_states=True
transformer_model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-large-cased', output_hidden_states=True)

input_ids = tf.keras.Input(shape=(128, ),dtype='int32')
attention_mask = tf.keras.Input(shape=(128, ), dtype='int32')

transformer = transformer_model([input_ids, attention_mask])    
hidden_states = transformer[1] # get output_hidden_states

hidden_states_size = 4 # count of the last states 
hiddes_states_ind = list(range(-hidden_states_size, 0, 1))

selected_hiddes_states = tf.keras.layers.concatenate(tuple([hidden_states[i] for i in hiddes_states_ind]))

# Now we can use selected_hiddes_states as we want
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(selected_hiddes_states)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(output)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs = [input_ids, attention_mask], outputs = output)
model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-4), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Is it possible to freeze the BERT model and train only the added layer? (or freeze some of the layers)

Comment: What is the hidden_states_size that you defined as being equal to 4? How can I find the correct value for different models (e.g. Roberta, Distillbert)?